# why environment variables (PATH) work in bash?

Tags: c, bash, environment-variables

i'm trying to built a bash using c.

but I faced this problem when I try this: `env -i bash`

this should pass a void `env` into bash so all the environment variables should be null

example :

```
➜  ~ env -i bash --norc
bash-3.2$ env
PWD=/Users/mbari
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
bash-3.2$ ls
#*mail*#78979jxq#       Documents               Pictures                result.log
Applications            Downloads               VirtualBox VMs          tmux-client-73012.log
Cleaner.sh              Library                 docker_start_up.bash    tmux-client-73105.log
Cleaner_42.sh           Movies                  file
Desktop                 Music                   goinfre
bash-3.2$
```

screenshot :
[image]

Comment: The ones you see are set internally by bash and do not come from anything external. This is expected behavior.

Comment: Not all variables are environment variables. Use `set` to list all of them, whether or not they are exported to the environment.

Comment: @that other guy, That said, the ones listed are exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash has a default path in case it does not inherit nor anything does not set PATH. It's defined as [DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE in bash sources](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/config-top.h#L65) and while there are some defaults in the source, usually distributions override this value in build scripts. As you're building your own shell, you might find that config file interesting.